# Is it possible to serialize a code configured StructureMap container for later use?

Tags: c#, serialization, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

I want to code a series of default StructureMap containers, then if customization is needed I can write them to the StructureMap xml configuration format making it possible to reconfigure and load them.

In essence, I am looking for `container.SaveConfigurationToXmlFile("someConfigFile.xml")`. The following is a code example. The construction of the container isn't the interesting part.

```
Container container = new Container(config=>
{
    SmartInstance<Person> travolta = config.For<IPerson>().Use<Person>()
        .Ctor<String>().Is("John Travolta");
    SmartInstance<Person> picard = config.For<IPerson>().Add<Person>()
        .Ctor<String>().Is("Captain Picard");
    SmartInstance<Person> ragen = config.For<IPerson>().Add<Person>()
        .Ctor<String>().Is("Ronald Ragen");
    SmartInstance<Person> obama = config.For<IPerson>().Add<Person>()
        .Ctor<String>().Is("Barak Obama");
    SmartInstance<Person> adams = config.For<IPerson>().Add<Person>()
        .Ctor<String>().Is("Brian Adams");

    SmartInstance<Driver> designatedDriver = config.For<IDriver>().Use<Driver>()
        .Ctor<IPerson>().Is(travolta);

    config.For<IVehicle>().Use<Car>().Named("CoolKidsCar")
        .Ctor<IDriver>().Is(designatedDriver)
        .Ctor<IPerson>("passengerSeat").Is(picard)
        .Ctor<IPerson>("leftBackSeat").Is(ragen)
        .Ctor<IPerson>("centerBackseat").Is(obama)
        .Ctor<IPerson>("rightBackseat").Is(adams)
        .Ctor<double>("topSpeed").Is(200);
});

string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "coolKidsContainer.xml");
container.SaveConfigurationToXmlFile(fileName); //Does not exist.
Container deserializedContainer = new Container(config => config.AddConfigurationFromXmlFile(fileName));

var defaultPerson = deserializedContainer.GetInstance<IPerson>();
var coolKidsCar = deserializedContainer.GetInstance<IVehicle>("CoolKidsCar");
```

Does this exist within StructureMap? Maybe some other IoC container can do it? What else can I do to get the same functionality?

Comment: Unlikely that such feature exists in ANY container, since XML configuration much less expressive than code based configurations are. Simple example: it is impossible to translate the registration of a lambda to XML.

Comment: Can't you extract the configuration logic to a `Configure(Container container)` method and perhaps package that method in its own dll?

Comment: @Steven Not exactly. An on-site technician from our commissioning team might do some XML reconfiguration by hand, or using an in-house configuration tool. I want the technician to be able to do minor adjustments to the existing configuration. Anyway, I think I might just bite the bullet and do the default configurations in XML myself. Thanks for the suggestions, anyway.

Comment: In my experience there are only a few parts of your DI wiring that should be changeable when deploying. Most would still need a recompile, or go through unit testing or even QA which makes exposing them as XML a false sense of flexibility and make the XML configuration more complex than needed. Instead, only expose the few parts that actually need to be changed by operations.

Comment: @Steven Yes, I think you are right. Doing most of the configuration in code and only let some of it be exposed as XML is the right way to go. It's mainly being able to use different sensors and preprocessing algorithms which will be configurable by changing the implementation of our interfaces through XML.